# What would be the best way to design a real time clock for the MSP430?

Tags: msp430, clock, timer, interrupts

Basically that. The way I am doing it now is with the TimerA set to 1 second interrupts. But I think that it's very annoying. Are there any other ways to do it?

I want to basically set timers on that clock, like, shutdown until 40 seconds have passed...

Comment: What is annoying about it?

Answer (score 4):

There are MSP430 devices with a low-power oscillator that use a standard 32.768 kHz watch crystal and are intended specifically for that sort of application. A typical one is the MSP430F1101.

Comment: Timer A and the watch crystal is the best way for the msp430 to keep time

Answer (score 4):

It's not perfectly clear to whether you want a real-time clock or a stopwatch (the 40 seconds you mention).

You could use an **RTC IC** (Real-Time Clock), like the NXP [PCF8563](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCF8563.pdf). This one is available in several packages, including both the old **DIL** and a very small **DFN**.
But you probably don't need a separate RTC IC. It's typically used because it consumes very **little power**, and the rest of the circuit can power down while the RTC keeps running of a battery or supercap. The MSP430, however, is also a low-power device, and it has a low-frequency oscillator which can run on the same 32.768kHz crystal you would use for the RTC.
In one project I had the MSP430 running continuously on a 32kHz crystal, and yet it consumed less than 5\$\mu\$A. That's more than an RTC (the PCF8563 only needs 250nA), but it will be acceptable for many applications.

What's your problem with the 1s interrupt? If you want to make a real-time clock you'll need a time-cue anyhow, whether generated internally or coming from an external RTC. Upon interrupt you can **perform required updates** of seconds, minutes and hour counters, and wait for the next interrupt. You even could work with **10ths of a second**, although with the 32.768kHz this will have a minor deviation. You would have four tenths of a second or 3277 clock ticks, followed by one tenth of 3278 ticks, to get exactly 1/2 second, so repeat this pattern a second time to complete one second.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a real-time clock is done by either having a real-time clock module built in to the microcontroller, or to use an external real-time clock module such as the [DS1305](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/2686) from Maxim.

These can typically be programmed to trigger an interrupt at a pre-defined time, and run off their own 32.768KHz crystal.  They often have their own battery-backup circuit, and some even contain charge circuits too.

Comment: That would be great, but I have an already developed platform, mainly a zolertia z1, which does not have any kind of realtime module. I can only rely on the microcontrollers clocks...